# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2}({x \over \sin x})^2dx$ using value of a given integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

**Question**

> If $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln({\sin x})dx = {\pi \over 2}\ln({1\over2})$ then find the value of $\int_0^{\pi/2}({x \over \sin x})^2dx$

I'm stumped. I have no clue what to do. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you have tried?

Comment: @zz20s I'm sorry to say that I haven't been able to try anything. I can't even begin the question. That's why I'd like a hint to expand on. I'll then edit what I could do.

Comment: $\ln\frac{A}{B}=\ln A-\ln B$

Comment: @almagest Aha.... I'm feeling incredibly stupid for having missed that....

Comment: Are you sure that the bound is correct? $\ln 0$ is not defined.

Comment: @zz20s actually I copied the question wrong... Wait a second, I'll edit it.

Comment: @zz20s There... There wasn't a ln function there. Complicates the question much more now.....

Comment: Is the upper bound, in the latter integral, equal to $\pi/2$ or equal to $\pi$?

Comment: @OlivierOloa It's $\pi /2$

Comment: @Gummybears Thanks. I give you an answer.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I'd appreciate if you start out with a hint so I can attempt the problem on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *First question, before the edit.*

  One may observe that $$ \int \frac1{\sin x}\:dx=\ln (\tan(x/2))+C. $$
  Then one may use an integration by parts, $$ \begin{align}
     \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin x}\:dx&=\left[x\ln
     (\tan(x/2))\right]_0^{\pi/2}-\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln (\tan(x/2))dx
     \\\\&=0-2\int_0^{\pi/4} \ln (\tan(u))du \\\\&=-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln
     v\:dv}{1+v^2}\quad (v=\tan u)
     \\\\&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1 v^{2n}\ln v \:dv
     \\\\&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \\\\&=2C \end{align}
     $$ where $C$ is the [Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).
- *Second question, after the edit.*

  One may observe that $$ \int \frac{-1}{(\sin x)^2}\:dx=\int
     \frac{(\cos x)'(\sin x)-(\sin x)'(\cos x)}{(\sin x)^2}\:dx=\int
     \left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)'dx=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+C. $$
  Then one may integrate by parts twice, $$ \begin{align}
     \int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2dx&=\left[-x^2\frac{\cos
     x}{\sin x}\right]_0^{\pi/2}+2\int_0^{\pi/2} x\:\frac{\cos x}{\sin
     x}dx \\\\&=0+2\left(\left[x\ln(\sin
     x)\right]_0^{\pi/2}-\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin x)\:dx\right)
     \\\\&=\pi\ln 2 \end{align} $$ using the assumed result.

Comment: The answer would be in terms of the values given. They have given the value of the integral of $ln(sinx)$. So the answer should be in terms of that.

Comment: @Gummybears Ok, maybe you may just consider my answer as an alternative path.

Comment: Ahh.... I see. But the question is actually multiple choice. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Is my answer in the multiple choice?

Comment: @Gummybears $2C$ is certainly the right answer. I know of no way of expressing $C$ in terms of $\pi\ln2$. What were the answers given (in the multiple choice question)?

Comment: @almagest $2 \pi ln2$, $\pi ln2$, $\pi ln2 \over 2$

Comment: @almagest I'm pretty sure we're not supposed to actually solve the integral. We have to use the information given to derive a result.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Unfortunately no. In fact, we haven't even been taught of this constant.

Comment: So your choices are 4.35517, 2.17759 and 1.08879. But the correct answer is 1.83193.

Comment: Ahh... I see.... Incredible question. Made even harder by the fact that it was written wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Please fix the question. It should be $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\frac{x}{\sin x})^2\ dx$ and the answer is $\pi\ln2$

FURTHER HINT: If we differentiate $x^2\cot x$ we get $2x\cot x-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}$. If we differentiate $x\ln\sin x$ we get $x\cot x+\ln\sin x$. And we are given the integral (over the relevant range) of $\ln\sin x$).

I agree that the tricky part is then evaluating $2x\ln\sin x$ and $x^2\cot x$ at $x=0$. You need to take the limit as $x\to 0$. They are 0 in both cases.

Comment: That's not what's given, but might be a typo. Can you show me how?

Comment: @Gummybears See my edit. Many thanks to almagest!