# Evaluating a maybe famous integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate :
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{x}{\cos x}\right)^2\text{d}x$$
Thx guys! I was wondering how would use a series expansion?

Comment: This integral does not converge, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%2Fcos(x))%5E2+from+0+to+pi%2F2

Comment: Related: [$\displaystyle\smash{\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \mathrm dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1747960/201168).

Comment: @Workaholic. Thank you for pointing out that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This improper integral diverges to $+\infty$: as $x\to (\pi/2)^-$,
$$\left(\frac{x}{\cos x}\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x-\pi/2)}\sim \frac{(\pi/2)^2}{(x-\pi/2)^2}.$$

Comment: Is C the Catalan's constant?

Comment: No, it is $\pi^2/4$